# Trying to search a sheet and copy row which matches

Tags: vba, function, excel

I believe this will take a macro, but would prefer something else.

Once I enter a name such as Bob into a cell, I would like it to check sheet A in column A for "Bob". If it locates a Bob, it copies the 11 cells to the right of Bob's name into the current sheet I am working on, to the right of where I had typed Bob.

Comment: You can use `VLOOKUP()` for this

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=VLOOKUP($B1,SheetA!$A:$L,COLUMN()+x,0)
```

in the cell immediately to the right of `Bob` and copied across eleven columns. Set `+x` to suit the column in which `Bob` is (eg to `-1` if `Bob` is in ColumnB).